# Expandable List in Boostrap 4

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have an expandable list in Bootrap 4 which works ok, except that other items won't collapse when one expands. Did I miss something or it isn't possible with list-groups. The example [shown](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/collapse/) using cards works fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Lorem Ipsum</title><!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="false">
        <ul class="list-group">
            <li role="tab" class="list-group-item" id="heading0">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse0" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse0" class="collapsed">1. List Group Item</a>
                <div id="collapse0" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading0">
                    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce pulvinar lorem quam, at commodo lorem dapibus sit amet. Etiam luctus varius lacus, eget rutrum massa egestas lacinia. Integer quis odio quis magna congue placerat. Cras sed venenatis orci. In velit quam, faucibus ac pharetra a, condimentum sed mi. Mauris nec sapien tincidunt, elementum lacus eget, auctor diam. Nunc vel posuere purus. Nullam accumsan non dolor nec congue. Nulla sagittis volutpat aliquam. </p>
                </div>
            </li>

            <li role="tab" class="list-group-item" id="headingOne">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne" class="collapsed">2. List Group Item</a>
                <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">

                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce pulvinar lorem quam, at commodo lorem dapibus sit amet. Etiam luctus varius lacus, eget rutrum massa egestas lacinia. Integer quis odio quis magna congue placerat. Cras sed venenatis orci. In velit quam, faucibus ac pharetra a, condimentum sed mi. Mauris nec sapien tincidunt, elementum lacus eget, auctor diam. Nunc vel posuere purus. Nullam accumsan non dolor nec congue. Nulla sagittis volutpat aliquam. </p>
                </div>
            </li>

            <li class="list-group-item" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo" class="collapsed">3. List Group Item</a>
                <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce pulvinar lorem quam, at commodo lorem dapibus sit amet. Etiam luctus varius lacus, eget rutrum massa egestas lacinia. Integer quis odio quis magna congue placerat. Cras sed venenatis orci. In velit quam, faucibus ac pharetra a, condimentum sed mi. Mauris nec sapien tincidunt, elementum lacus eget, auctor diam. Nunc vel posuere purus. Nullam accumsan non dolor nec congue. Nulla sagittis volutpat aliquam. </p>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Hi, please provide a [mcve]. I don't see any bootstrap in this code snippet.

Comment: Sorry, just a moment.

Comment: Have you tried using Bootstrap 4s Beta release as well as the code specific to the accordion effect w/ `collapse`: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/#accordion-example

Comment: Thanks, tried Beta just now. That didn't work either. This is based on the example, which works, except that this uses list-groups instead of cards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: This] This works if anyone else needs it:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Lorem Ipsum</title><!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="false">
        <ul class="list-group">
            <li role="tab" class="list-group-item" id="heading0" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#collapse0" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse0" class="collapsed">   1. List Group Item </li>
                <div id="collapse0" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading0">
                    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce pulvinar lorem quam, at commodo lorem dapibus sit amet. Etiam luctus varius lacus, eget rutrum massa egestas lacinia. Integer quis odio quis magna congue placerat. Cras sed venenatis orci. In velit quam, faucibus ac pharetra a, condimentum sed mi. Mauris nec sapien tincidunt, elementum lacus eget, auctor diam. Nunc vel posuere purus. Nullam accumsan non dolor nec congue. Nulla sagittis volutpat aliquam. </p>
                </div>


            <li role="tab" class="list-group-item" id="headingOne" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne" class="collapsed">2. List Group Item</li>
                <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">

                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce pulvinar lorem quam, at commodo lorem dapibus sit amet. Etiam luctus varius lacus, eget rutrum massa egestas lacinia. Integer quis odio quis magna congue placerat. Cras sed venenatis orci. In velit quam, faucibus ac pharetra a, condimentum sed mi. Mauris nec sapien tincidunt, elementum lacus eget, auctor diam. Nunc vel posuere purus. Nullam accumsan non dolor nec congue. Nulla sagittis volutpat aliquam. </p>
                </div>


            <li class="list-group-item" role="tab" id="headingTwo" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo" class="collapsed">3. List Group Item</li>
                <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce pulvinar lorem quam, at commodo lorem dapibus sit amet. Etiam luctus varius lacus, eget rutrum massa egestas lacinia. Integer quis odio quis magna congue placerat. Cras sed venenatis orci. In velit quam, faucibus ac pharetra a, condimentum sed mi. Mauris nec sapien tincidunt, elementum lacus eget, auctor diam. Nunc vel posuere purus. Nullam accumsan non dolor nec congue. Nulla sagittis volutpat aliquam. </p>
                </div>

        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```